# Popen redirected to file, but file not created soonenough

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, flush

I run an external exe from python3 that redirects to file

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('app.exe > out.txt', shell=True, stdout=sub.PIPE)
```

but after, when I check if it's created sometimes it says no, but file is actually there:

```
assert exists('out.txt') and isfile('out.txt')
```

I suspect there is some buffering going on, how can I flush it to disk?

sys.stdout.flush()

didn't help.
Adding artificial delays is too hacky.
Using win10.

Comment: As an aside, you should probably prefer `run` over bare `Popen` unless you know exactly why not.